# Exporting Data from Cassandra to CSV file

Tags: csv, cassandra, export, export-to-csv

**Table Name : Product**

```
uid                                  | productcount | term                 | timestamp

304ad5ac-4b6d-4025-b4ea-8b7991a3fe72 |           26 |                dress | 1433110980000
6097e226-35b5-4f71-b158-a1fe39a430c1 |            0 |              #751104 | 1433861040000
```

Command :

```
COPY product (uid, productcount, term, timestamp) TO 'temp.csv';
```

Error:

```
Improper COPY command.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: formatted question and removed thanking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of your original COPY command is also fine. The problem is with your column named timestamp, which is a data type and is a reserved word in this context. For this reason you need to escape your column name as follows:

```
COPY product (uid, productcount, term, "timestamp") TO 'temp.csv';
```

Even better, try to use a different field name, because this can cause other problems as well.

Comment: oh. I didn't realize that.Thanks a lot man.I'll change the column name to avoid any  future conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to export the data into CSV files by using by below command. 
Avoiding the column names did the trick.

```
copy product to 'temp.csv' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following commands to get the data from **Cassandra Tables to CSV**

This command will copy **Top 100 rows** to CSV file.

```
cqlsh -e"SELECT * FROM employee.employee_details" > /home/hadoop/final_Employee.csv
```

This command will copy **All the rows** to CSV file.

```
cqlsh -e"PAGING OFF;SELECT * FROM employee.employee_details" > /home/hadoop/final_Employee.csv
```